# when assigning value to a pointer: Expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++

I encountered some problem when writing c++. The problem might be symplified as below. The function named as "test" return a pointer. And I tried to modify it but failed with error information.

```
void* test(){ void * p1; return p1}
test() = new string();
```

ERROR: expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
In my case, p1 is not a local variable but a certain member of an object. And it failed too.

Comment: If p1 is member - you need to return reference to it to be able to assign to this pointer

Comment: Using "naked" pointers is discouraged. (C++11 brought you [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), use them.) Tossing pointers around as `void *` (and thus abandoning type safety) is *very much* discouraged.

Comment: Even if you *were* allowed to assign to the returned pointer the returned value is *a copy* of `p1`, so assigning to it doesn't change `p1` anyway. So would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 2):

`test()` returns a pointer, it is not a variable, therefore you can't assign anything to it.

If you simply want a void pointer you can just use `void* variable_name = new string()` or whatever you want to assign to it.

Answer (score 1):

@MikaelMello is correct that you cannot set the value of a function.

Extending your code and @MikaelMello 's, you can take the pointer that your function returns and make it point to an object like this:

```
void* test(){ void * p1; return p1}
...
void* voidPointer = test();
voidPointer = new string();
```

Answer (score 0):

The lvalue must be a variable. it cannot be a function. When we use assignment operator "=", what program does is, it assigns the value in the right hand side of the assignment(called the rvalue) to the left hand side value(called the lvalue). So the lvalue must be a variable that have memory to store some value in it.

In your program the lvalue is a function test() which does not have any memory to store anything therefore throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

the function `test` has a return type of `void *`, thus the expression `test()` is a rvalue, which cannot be assigned to. only lvalue can appear on the left of an assignment operator. see the [explanation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of lvalue, rvalue, and others.

I'm guessing you probably want to dereference a pointer and assign a new value to it. but if you really want to assign to a return value of a function, the return type must be a lvalue reference type. like

```
// this function returns a reference to a pointer
void * &test ();
test() = new string;
```

you really know what the code should mean, right? if you return a dangling reference and assign value to it, even the syntax has the correct type, the program is still not correct.